# List the elements of G

Tags: abstract-algebra

So we are asked to write out the elements of G and H where G= $ \mathbb{Z}/ <20> $ and

H = $<4, 20>$ . I understand how to do H and I got: 
{$0 + <20>, 4 + <20> , 8 + <20>, 12 + <20>, 16 + <20>$ } from here through, would G=
{$1+ <20>, 2+ <20>, 3+ <20>$, etc....} or how do I find this???

Comment: Why did this question receive **two** downvotes?  The OP clearly posted the question and their attempts.... I swear I don't understand the purpose of this downvote system (or why so many people downvote but don't leave a comment explaining why).  The system is too often abused.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are correct about both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your $G$ is correct... But you are mentioning $H=<4,20>$, now see $<20>$ $\subset <4>$, so $<4,20>=<4>$ = {$0, \pm4, \pm 8 \ldots \ldots$}.